# Add "Host" to "Cache key settings" will cause "NoSuchBucket" error

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I encounter a problem. When I edit the cache policy by going to "Cache key settings" -> "Headers - Include the following headers" and add "Host" to the list, then when I try to visit a file from Cloudfront, I get the following error:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
<BucketName>d2mamsrhkq8bo4.cloudfront.net</BucketName>
<RequestId>DSWSX73HEC9E5N2V</RequestId>
<HostId>g8dnFseJ5vfMivTcIolD1C5ap2bCbKILRhX1Yk91Xdyq/MnA6dj6FLqjMyQ21IdXr8iS3wtv628=</HostId>
</Error>
```

But before adding the "Host" header, everything is fine.